# Detecting Curly/ MS Smart Quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, ms-word, ms-office

Im doing some user input validation (mostly french characters). first i am trying to detect the characters if they are entered into the textbox. However, I am having trouble trying to detect MS Smart quotes (curly quotes). The code is not recognizing smart quotes. Im not sure if maybe when im testing if im not actually inputting smart quotes, or if its something wrong with the regex. MS Smart quote code is the last 2 js conditions.

```
   <body>

    <script>
        function addComment() {

            var comm = document.getElementById("comment").value;

            if (!(comm.indexOf('\u0152') === -1))
            {
                alert('found OE ligature');
            }
            else if (!(comm.indexOf('\u0153') === -1))
            {
                alert('found oe ligature');
            }
            else if (!(comm.indexOf('\xAB') === -1))
            {
                alert('found <<');
            }
            else if (!(comm.indexOf('\xBB') === -1))
            {
                alert('found >>');
            }
            else if ((comm.match([/[\u201C\u201D\u201E]/g]) ))
            {
                alert('found MS Smart  double quotes and apostrophe ');
            }
             else if ((comm.match(/[\u2018\u2019\u201A]/g) ))
            {
                alert('found MS Smart  single  quotes and apostrophe ');
            }

        }


    </script>



    <input type="text" id="comment" onblur="addComment()">



</body>
```

Comment: What is the `document.getElementById("comment").value`?

Comment: ‘ “ ”     
- 
This is what im using as the value to test the smart quote conditions. 

@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: The quotes [are detected](https://jsfiddle.net/99uby69r/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew

Wow. I did some editing on the code when pasting it to stackoverflow. but didnt test out on my ide. thanks for taking the time to help. appreciate it.

Comment: Hey. It seems single quotes are detected. But double quotes are not.  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: There [should be no `[]` around `string.match`](https://jsfiddle.net/99uby69r/2/) and also, no need specifying `/g`. To test if a regex matches a string, use `RegExp.test()` with no `/g` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The last 2 `else if` blocks have some issues. First, the one checking smart double quotes is unnecessarily wrapped with `[...]`. Secod, if you need to check if a string matches a pattern, use `RegExp#test()` (without the global modifier).

So, I suggest using

```js
//var comm = "‘ “ ” ";
var comm = "‘  ";
if (!(comm.indexOf('\u0152') === -1)) {
    alert('found OE ligature');
  } else if (!(comm.indexOf('\u0153') === -1)) {
    alert('found oe ligature');
  } else if (!(comm.indexOf('\xAB') === -1)) {
    alert('found <<');
  } else if (!(comm.indexOf('\xBB') === -1)) {
    alert('found >>');
  } else if (/[\u201C\u201D\u201E]/.test(comm)) {
    alert('found MS Smart  double quotes and apostrophe ');
  } else if (/[\u2018\u2019\u201A]/.test(comm)) {
    alert('found MS Smart  single  quotes and apostrophe ');
  }
```